# Recursive Scrapy crawling issues

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I am trying to do a recursive spider to extract content from a site (example: web.com) which has a specific link structure. For example:

http://web.com/location/profile/12345678?qid=1403226397.5971&source=location&rank=21

http://web.com/location/profile/98765432?qid=1403366850.3991&source=locaton&rank=1

As you can see only the numeric portions of the URLs are changing and I need to crawl all the links following this URL structure and extract itemX, itemY, and itemZ.

I have translated the link structure into regex as this: '\d+?qid=\d+.\d+&source=location&rank=\d+'. And the Python-Scrapy code as follows, however, after I run the spider, nothing is extracted by the spider:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from web.items import webItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy import log
import re
import urllib

class web_RecursiveSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "web_RecursiveSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["web.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://web.com/location/profile",]

    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('\d+?qid=\d+.\d+&source=location&rank=\d+', ),) 
    , callback="parse_item", follow= True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//*')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = webItem()
            item["itemX"] = site.select("//span[@itemprop='X']/text()").extract()
            item["itemY"] = site.select("//span[@itemprop='Y']/text()").extract()
            item["itemZ"] = site.select("//span[@itemprop='Z']/text()").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape `?` mark in the regular expression:

```
'\d+\?qid=\d+.\d+&source=location&rank=\d+'
    ^
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> url = "http://web.com/location/profile/12345678?qid=1403226397.5971&source=location&rank=21"
>>> print re.search('\d+?qid=\d+.\d+&source=location&rank=\d+', url)
None
>>> print re.search('\d+\?qid=\d+.\d+&source=location&rank=\d+', url)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10be538b8>
```

Note that you also need to escape the dot, but it doesn't affect the examples you've provided:

```
'\d+\?qid=\d+\.\d+&source=location&rank=\d+'
             ^
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be one of the issues. I have tried your demo in Scrapy shell and it confirms the regex should be working now. However, when I run the entire code via 'scrapy crawl web_RecursiveSpider -o items.csv -t csv', the CSV file still extracts nothing. The cmd output says "... ScrapyDeprecationWarning... .Myspider inherits from deprecated class scrapy.spider.BaseSpider, please inherit from scrapy.spider.Spider... INFO: Crawled 0 pages"

Comment: I am not sure if the "deprecation" warning is the issue since I have other working crawlers despite this warning. Any suggestions or tips will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @KubiK888 nope, deprecation warning is not related to the problem. Could you check that the links are followed at least? Put a print statement inside the `parse_item` and inside the loop too. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried your advice, and here is what I got. 1) Placing the print statement after the last import and before 'class FourOneOne_RecursiveSpider(CrawlSpider)': OK

2) After 'rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor... follow= True),)' and before 'def parse_item': OK

3) After 'def parse_item(self, response): ... items = []' and before 'for site in sites:': NO

4) Within 'for site in sites:' loop before 'return items': NO.

Comment: Hi @alecxe. Nope, I am kind of waiting for additional help after following your instructions, sorry I am a Python newbie. I did look over other similar topics on the site, though couldn't find an answer. I did try to take out everything for the regex, meaning leaving an empty () after the 'allow', and run the spider. It seems to be running and going through the general links in that specific site. So I *guess* there is still something wrong with the regex? I did try different things with the directory and regex, nothing seems to solve the issue.